# How to fix a Corrupted USB

Tags: windows-vista, usb-flash-drive, disk-management

My USB stick has suddenly stopped working. It's a Busbi 4GB. My USB used to be G:/ but as soon as I plugged it in, I used to get a pop up box showing that it was plugged in.

Now, when I plug this in, it shows as I:/ and no pop up box appears. It shows in my computer as I:/ and when I click to open it says I:/ is not accessible the disk structure is corrupted and unreadable. I have tried to change the file name back to G:/ but nothing happened (this was under disk management).

On disk management, it shows Volume as `I:/ Layout simple Type Basic File system RAW status Healthy (Active,Primary partition) Capacity 3.42GB`. I've tried right clicking properties then the tab tools and click error checking (this option will check the volume for errors). When I click "check now" it comes up with the disk check could not be performed because Windows cannot access the disk.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware error if it can't access the disk. Either rejoice because you remembered to make backups, or take a moment to understand that this is why we make backups.

Comment: Did you try deleting the partition, recreating it and formatting anew using Disk Management? If it doesn't work, probably time to get a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If the data on the USB is not that important why don't you just format the USB drive again?

Here's how to format it :

1. Plug it to your computer .
2. Go to 'My Computer' and right-click on the USB drive and select "Format".
3. Select FAT32 and not NTFS as format.

If this doesn't work format it using [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html).This should fix it.

To recover the data lost on formatting, you might want to try to use one of the [free recovery tools](https://superuser.com/questions/62687/how-to-recover-a-mysteriously-deleted-folder) out. [Reccuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) is one of the best recovery tools you may try.

Answer (score 1):

`File system RAW`? That's not right, that's probably what the problem is. Windows probably can't read the "RAW" data. Unfortunately, the only fix for this is to format it as FAT32 (it should've been FAT32 to begin with).

However, if you have another computer with an OS or know of a download that can read raw data, then you can recover the data before formatting as FAT32 (most common file system for removable devices).

Good luck, hope this helps. If not drop a comment, and I'll look into the problem further

Answer (score 1):

Try the Disk Check from the Command Prompt; In the Search Bar or Start\Run command, type: `CMD.exe`. Next type: `chkdsk i: /r` (no quotes) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Worked for me on 2 drives yesterday and today solving the same exact HDD problem.

(There is a space between `chkdsk` and `I` and there is a space between `:` and `/`)
Substitute your actual corrupted drive letter for the `i`.  e.g. if drive `E` is corrupted, use 
`chkdsk e: /r`

On a 2TB drive it took about 12 hours, but recovered *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

If the data on the drive in NOT important:

1) Try to format this drive.

2) If you can't format it. Go to the USB developer website, find special software to recover exactly your USB stick.

If the data is very important:

- go to the hetmanrecovery.com
- download "[Hetman Partition Recovery](https://hetmanrecovery.com/hard_drive_recovery/software.htm)" software, and try to scan this USB stick for lost files.

> Hetman Partition Recovery will reliably restore information from damaged FAT and NTFS disks, recovering the original file and folder structure. In addition to existing partitions, the tool discovers all previously created volumes. This allows the user to search and recover files from those deleted volumes. The tool can save the entire logical drive, recovering the original file and folder structure.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Since you are recommending software in the latter part of your answer, please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!