# How to RECOVER deleted files

Tags: backup, data-recovery, file-recovery, recovery

I ran batch *command prompt* below (Win10 ent version), ***purge*** switch **deleted** all my files a level up within that folder (on a *WD My Passport* physical drive (password protected)),

`robocopy D:\X-folder G:\Y-folder\ /s /purge /xj /np /tee /r:0 /w:0 /mt:32 /xf desktop.ini /log:logbkup_x240_downloads.txt`

Solutions attempted,

- Lost files can be seen and recoverable on both *Recuva* and *Lazesoft* recovery software. See *Recuva* screenshot,

[image: recuva_screenshot]

- Recovered files (e.g. `.jpg`) are not readable,

[image]

- I have also tried *PC Inspector File Recovery*, it seems all ended up with following error **can't read file header** after recovery,

[image]

I very much APPRECIATE any suggestion for any **RECOVERY** methods, urgent!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a mysteriously deleted folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/62687/how-to-recover-a-mysteriously-deleted-folder)

Comment: Thanks @harrymc. Just attempted with _PC INSPECTOR File Recovery 4_, which found all lost files but after recovery (selected a few `.jpg` for testing), Windows still failed to read those recovered files, i.e. I suspect sth to do with its headers entry. IrfanView gives error note: **_Can't read file header_**!

Comment: These utilities are not guaranteed to succeed. See also [this list](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm). DON'T modify anything on the disk while doing that.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the list, all _recovery software_ I tried on seem be able to scan and found the lost files, but the files are **unreadable**; even file size and format extension seems fine to me. Very painful!

Comment: Re _recovered but **unreadable**_ - On _Recuva_, despite the lost files are "visually" available for recovery, just realised on _Header_ tab, shows all "0"(s) . Any ideas and thanks in advance.